# Setup output and input audio on different cards

Tags: usb, audio, alsa

I was trying to prepare my RPi for jasper and plugged the USB mic and the speakers in the 3.5 jack. Trying to configure it I found out that I could only chose that the whole audio IO is going through USB with 1 or through the 3.5 jack with 0 when configuring the `alsa.conf` file. Is there a way to make my setup work? I think it was possible in Raspbian *Wheezy*, because they said in their documentation that you need some speaker which work with the headphone jack of the Pi.

**EDIT**

arecord -l :

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So I got that my `card 1` is the one with the mic and `card 0` is with the aux output and HDMI output. According to the jasper documentation I have set my `alsa.conf` like this:

```
...
# show all name hints also for definitions without hint {} section
defaults.namehint.showall on
# show just basic name hints
defaults.namehint.basic on
# show extended name hints
defaults.namehint.extended on
#
defaults.ctl.card 1 #<- changed from 0 to 1
defaults.pcm.card 1 #<- changed from 0 to 1
defaults.pcm.device 0
...
```

And I made a `.asoundrc` file in the root directory with these options:

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

If I leave the `alsa.conf` on 0, I am able to play something with *aplay*, but putting it on 1 doesn't allow me to play it (of course, because on card 1 is the mic). Also calling `alsamixer` gives me only the **bcm2835** card, which is my output card if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Are you using PulseAudio, or do your programs access ALSA directly?

Comment: I was doing it with the alsa.conf file. And also with .asoundrc file in /root

Comment: What did you try in those files?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get different definitions for playback and capture, use the `asym` device:

```perl
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:0"
    capture.pcm  "plughw:1"
}
```

(Something like this is not possible for control devices.)

Comment: I will try that as soon as I can. Do I have to do that also on the ctl part too? I am asking because I don't know what pcm and ctl stands for. And what does control device mean?

Comment: `ctl.xxx` defines a control device.

Comment: Now I am really able to use both of them. So I am able to do aplay and arecord without changing anything in my conf files. What do you recomment to set the default ctl? On the card with the Audio Jack or on the USB card?

Comment: Well, which one do you want to see when you run `alsamixer`?

Comment: Well, I think that isn't that important for me... So the important one is pcm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would this work for streaming from a usb microphone to a bluetooth speaker?

Comment: @NaderGhanbari These definitions specify what device actually gets accessed when an application opens the device named `default`.

Comment: Thanks, my use case was different. I couldn't make it work this way though. Ended up streaming it from the usb mic and capturing the stream in another node.